# Enable Captcha after several login failure - How to implement this?

Tags: php, security, authentication, captcha

I'm working on an auth system with login failure.
If the user fails to login, the attempts number in database is incremented and if a defined limit is reached, PHP sets a session captcha variable to true.
So when the user (or spam bot) gets the login page again, a captcha form is shown thanks to the session variable

But since Spam bots could eventually delete the session cookie and retry, this may be not  effective.

Should I use a database solution instead ? How would you implement this (with/or without the database) ?

Comment: You could use IP addresses and track in the database the number of attempts from a particular IP address.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spam bots can get around session restrictions fairly easily, so it would have to be done in the database to be effective. Spam bots can also change their IP address each request, although this is harder to achieve.

You'd have to put a login attempts field in the users table that starts at 0, increment this when they get the password wrong, and reset it to 0 when they log in successfully. When someone tries to login as a user with login attempts > 5 you would then take them to another page with the captcha which they must enter correctly (even if the password was wrong).

Comment: In addition to that, I would add IP tracking so that if somebody is trying to guess the username, they will be required to enter captcha even if they use different usernames on different attempts.

Comment: One problem with this method is that if implemented badly you could very effectively block out any user you like for as long as you'd like...

Comment: @Cyber-GuardEnterprise you wouldn't be blocking them out, you're only making that user have to type a capatcha code, not too much of a hassel for the user. You could add a captchaExpires timestamp field to the table.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply record the user's session variable and then count how many times the form is submitted for an IP address.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of View just take username when he attempt to login on your PHP page if he/she fails to attempt then store the username in Login_attempts tables and its IP address also. Increment the failed attempts column and check whether it is greater than threshold value of yours let say 5 and if it failed then add captcha to it and also check side by side IP is not changing with each attempts with certain time interval let say for 1 min IP address should remain same if it fails then fail the login attempts.

For best use `NOSQL or memcache` to retrieve fast data from database.